# escape special character in perl when splitting a string

Tags: regex, perl, split

i have a file in this format

```
string: string1
string: string2
string: string3
```

i want to split the lines by `space` and `:`,so initially i wrote this:

```
my @array = split(/[:\s]/,$lineOfFile);
```

the result wasn't as expected, because inside `@array` the `split` inserts also `white space` , so after some researches i understood that i have to escape the `\s` so i wrote

```
my @array = split(/[:\\s]/,$lineOfFile);
```

why i have to escape `\s`, the character `:` isn't a special character or not?

can someone explain me that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If the data is of the format `string: string1` (the interesting part being "colon-space", wouldn't it be better to split on "colon-space" than on "colon or space"?  Even with a `+` quantifier, you would still be imprecisely splitting on "any number of colons and/or spaces".  In other words, `split /:\s/, $lineOfFile;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* have to double up the backslash. Have you tried it?

```
split /[:\\s]/, $line
```

will split on a colon `:` *or* a backslash `\` *or* a small S `s`, giving

```
("", "tring", " ", "tring1")
```

which isn't what you want at all. I suggest you split on a colon followed by zero or more spaces

```
my @fields = split /:\s*/, $line
```

which gives this result

```
("string", "string1")
```

which I think is what you want.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Then your code isn't as you have shown. At a guess you are putting your regex into a string variable before applying the regex. Something like `my $re = "[:\\s]"; my @fields = split $re, $line;`, which is a very different thing. That split will also give you *three* fields `("string", "", "string1")` instead of just the two you are interested in, because you are splitting on the colon and the whitespace *separately*.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Please don't delete your comments. Whether right or wrong, it puts any subsequent comments out of context.

Comment: `string: string1` is a example i don't have strings which start with `s`

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Then why split on `s`? If you remove the `s` and do just `split /[:\\]/, $line` then the backslash is pointless as you have no backslashes in any of your strings and you are just splitting on colons. That will leave a space at the start of the second field, like `("string", " string1")`

Comment: why `split` leaves a space at the start of the new field?

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Do you mean at the start of the second field? It's because the pattern `/[:\\s]/` doesn't include any spaces or `\s`: it's just a colon `:`, a backslash "\" (because you doubled the backslash) and `s`.

Comment: yes i meant second field, ok so for example i can just write this `/: /` ? more simple to read and write.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Yes, but it's safer to allow for variations in the number of spaces, for example if someone has edited the data manually. `/:\s*/` is much better, and it's hardly complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to double escape `\s` and the colon is not a character of special meaning. But in your case, it makes sense to avoid using a character class altogether and split on a colon followed by whitespace "one or more" times.

```
my @array = split(/:\s+/, $lineOfFile);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you explain me the differences by using this `/[:\s]/` and `/:\s/`, the first splits for  `:` or `\s` the second only for `: ` right?

Comment: so in my case `/: /` works as well as `/:\s/` or `/:\s+/` right?

Comment: The difference between a `<space>` and `\s` is that a space matches a space character while `\s` matches different kinds of whitespace such as tab, newline, carriage return ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `/[:\s]/` only searches for a single character. Thus, when applying this regex, you get something like

```
print $array[0], ' - ', $array[1], ' - ', $array[2];

string -  - string1
```

because it splits between `:` and the whitespace before `string1`. The string `string: string1` is therefore splitted into three parts, `string`, the empty place between `:` and the whitespace and `string1`. However, allowing more characters

```
my @array = split(/[:\s]+/,$lineOfFile);
```

works well, since `:`+whitespace is used for splitting.

```
print $array[0], ' - ', $array[1];

string - string1
```

Comment: `/[...]/` can be used to match a set of characters for example `/[,:;]/` -> split for `,` or `:` or `;` or not?

Comment: Yes, but only for *one* of those at a time. In your case you have `: `, which are two characters. Thus you need `/[...]+/`.

Comment: i don't understand `but only for one of those at a time` , for example if i have a string like `hello:stack:oveflow` i can write this -> `/:/` and works, without using `/:/+`

Comment: Right, but `hello::stack::oveflow` would not.